# Outlook add-in publish on a Cpanel

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I want to know if it is possible to publish an Outlook add-in made in on VsCode on other servers like Cpanel or it's exclusive on Azure?
And after only put the manifest to point the domain that was publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish/host your add-in on any web sever of your choosing.
One thing to keep in mind, however, is that, for your add-in to support Single Sign-On, you need to register it via the Azure portal for app registrations using the credentials of a Microsoft 365 tenant. Otherwise, you don't need to worry about Azure here. Just set the SourceLocation in the manifest to point to the location of your add-in's code on your domain.