# Error publishing Outlook Add-In to CPanel

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've seen other questions regarding this subject, including some with answers. I believe I'm doing everything other people have recommended to solve this issue and also found in Microsoft's docs, but for some reason, I'm getting a CORS error while loading my plugin, so I need more help.

The main related question to what I'm trying to do is this: [Outlook add-in publish on a Cpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69713131/outlook-add-in-publish-on-a-cpanel)

I already tested my addin, and it works. On the test, I'm loading everything from localhost, as shown in the MS documentation, this way:

```
http-server -S --cors . -p 3000
office-addin-https-reverse-proxy --url http://localhost:3000
```

After that, to allow it to run from localhost, I need to open a new TAB (besides the outlook one) and load at least one resource directly from localhost to be able to instruct the browser to trust localhost (I don't have a default setting to trust localhost).

What happens is that when I publish the plugin to my site, Outlook doesn't allow it to run, and I get an error on the browser's JS console complaining about 'sameorigin':

```
Refused to display 'https://mailsig.leadcomm.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

There's an article on Microsoft's Documentation entitled
[Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations), but it only addresses calls explicitly done using XmlHttpRequest, which is not my case.

My manifest sets all configurations for both `<AppDomain>` and `<SourceLocation>`, so I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. The only detail is that my company's site is **NOT** hosted with Microsoft but in a regular CPanel hosting provider. I have a valid SSL certificate applied on the site, which also conforms to MS specifications.

Can anyone point to me what I'm doing wrong and how to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue myself. After some research, I found out that, even though I didn't configure it this way, recent versions of cPanel use several settings to improve security, and amongst them, for Apache:

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
```

This default setting was causing my Add-In rejection by the browser since the parent frame to which the add-in would be attached wasn't coming from the "same origin" as my Add-in (the parent frame is Outlook's main frame, which comes from Microsoft's servers).

To solve the issue, I added the following settings to the .htaccess file on my website:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```

After adding the above settings to .htaccess, everything started working as planned. I hope this information helps someone else - I know how hard I tried to find this!